# Local notifications are not being added

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have code that used to work until recently. It is supposed to schedule a number of local notifications based on a list of given dates.

The code looks like this:

```
static func scheduleNotifications()
{
    // Here, a list of dates when notifications should appear is
    // created. This is called pendingNotifications. It contains
    // a list of dates and the number of events on that date
    ...

    // Now I want to schedule up to 20 local notifications for
    // each of the dates. The badge should show the number of events
    let sortedDates = pendingNotifications.keys.sorted()
    for i in 0 ..< min(20, sortedDates.count)
    {
        let notificationDate = ...

        let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
        content.title = "The title"
        content.body = "The description"
        content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
        content.badge = NSNumber(value: pendingNotifications[sortedDates[i]]!)

        let ident = UUID().uuidString
        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: calendar.dateComponents(in: calendar.timeZone, from: notificationDate), repeats: false)
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: ident, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        center.add(request) { error in
            center.getPendingNotificationRequests() { requests in
                print(requests.count)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code executes without error, but the request count I print in the completion handler always outputs 0 and I don't get any notification displayed.

Then I have a second function that just schedules a sample notification independently of any other criteria:

```
static func scheduleSampleNotification()
{
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "Test"
    content.body = "Sample Notification!"
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default()
    content.badge = 5

    let ident = UUID().uuidString
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: false)
    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: ident, content: content, trigger: trigger)
    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.add(request)
}
```

If I add a line to `scheduleNotifications` that calls `scheduleSampleNotification` right before the comment I wrote about the list of dates being created, the number of pending requests is always 1 and the sample notification also appears after a minute.

I actually don't know what I'm doing wrong here and I'm a bit lost, especially as the same code worked fine before I changed the minimum required iOS version from 9 to 10.3 (in the previous version I checked whether I was running on iOS 9 and used the old way to provide local notifications - now I removed that code as from 10.3 I understand you're supposed to use `UNUserNotificationCenter`).

I'm testing in the simulator and on an iOS 12 device. I use XCode 10.1.

---

**EDIT**
Interesting: When I change from `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` to `UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger` all the notifications are scheduled. Maybe something's wrong with my trigger - but all the dates are in the future?

---

**EDIT 2**
OK, I found the problem. Obviously, the following does not work anymore:

```
let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(in: calendar.timeZone, from: notificationDate)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
```

while the following does work:

```
let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute], from: notificationDate)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
```

No idea why, especially as it used to work before...

Comment: Is 'notificationDate' being set correctly?

Comment: Yes, the date is set correctly. I noticed, as I wrote in my latest edit, that specifying the date components (day, month, year, hour, minute) instead of taking all the components for the given time zone makes it work. I have no idea why...

Comment: Yeah that seems strange.

Comment: @Chris As it turns out, I had used the `if @available(` statement wrong (doh!), so the code above was actually never executed! Instead, the code for iOS 9 was executed, so all along I had been using a deprecated API without really knowing it. This still leaves the question open why the full date components don't work while the other solution does. Going to post a follow up question on that...

Comment: What about setting the trigger equal to notificationDate directly?

Comment: @Chris What do you mean? The trigger needs to be a `UNCalendarNotificationTrigger` and that requires date components. Can a date be used as date components directly (I'm relatively new to iOS development, so the question may sound a bit dumb...)?

Comment: You’re right - I got confused. Just checked how I had used it in a project and indeed it was date components rather than a Date object.