# UNCalendarNotificationTrigger won't work with full date components

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

In [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54097281/local-notifications-are-not-being-added) I mentioned a problem scheduling local notifications. The real cause for the problem was that I used to following code to create the trigger, which does not work:

```
let calendar = ...
let notificationDate = ...

let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents(in: calendar.timeZone, from: notificationDate)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
```

The following code does work, however:

```
let calendar = ...
let notificationDate = ...

let dateComponents = calendar.dateComponents([.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute], from: notificationDate)
let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: false)
```

So the question is: What's happening here? Why does the latter work while the former does not?

Answer (score 4):

It seems to be that if you provide date components that are way too specific, it won't match for the trigger. It says in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/uncalendarnotificationtrigger/1649772-init) to "Provide only the date components that are relevant for your trigger."

I ran into this issue too, and I found that `[.day, .month, .year, .hour, .minute, .second]` is usually safe.